# SWI Prolog Array Retrive [Index and Element]

Tags: arrays, indexing, prolog, element

I'm trying to program an array retrieval in swi-prolog. With the current code printed below I can retrieve the element at the given index but I also want to be able to retrieve the index[es] of a given element.

```
aget([_|X],Y,Z) :- Y \= 0, Y2 is (Y-1), aget(X,Y2,Z).
aget([W|_],Y,Z) :- Y = 0, Z is W.
```

Example 1: aget([9,8,7,6,5],1,N) {Retrieve the element 8 at index 1}
output: N = 9. {Correct}

Example 2: aget([9,8,7,6,5],N,7) {retrieve the index 2 for Element 7}
output: false {incorrect}

The way I understood it was that swi-prolog would work in this way with little no additional programing. So clearly I'm doing something wrong. If you could point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code it's too procedural, and the second clause it's plainly wrong, working only for numbers.

The functionality you're looking for is implemented by [nth0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth0/3)/3. In SWI-Prolog you can see the optimized source with `?- edit(nth0).` An alternative implementation has been discussed here on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9803727/874024) my answer).

Note that Prolog *doesn't* have arrays, but lists. When an algorithm can be rephrased to avoid indexing, then we should do.

Answer (score 0):

If you represent arrays as compounds, you can also use the ISO standard predicate arg/3 to access an array element. Here is an example run:

```
?- X = array(11,33,44,77), arg(2,X,Y).
X = array(11, 33, 44, 77),
Y = 33.
```

The advantage over lists is that the compound access needs O(1) time and whereas the list access needs O(n) time, where n is the length of the array.