# How to take the head of one list in a list of lists and put it in another list?

Tags: prolog

I have a list of lists, which looks something like this:

```
[[b,c],[],[a]]
```

I want to write a predicate that will take a specific letter from the top of one of the lists, and put it in another list. The letter to be moved is specified beforehand. It can be placed on top of a list which is either empty, or contains a letter that is larger (b can be placed on c, but not otherwise). The letter should be removed from the original list after it has been moved.

I am having trouble telling Prolog to look for a list which starts with the specified letter, and also how to tell Prolog to put this in another list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution, based no `[nth1][1]/4` (well, you should read documentation for `nth0/4`, really)

```
/* takes a specific letter from the top of one of the lists, and puts it in another list.
   The letter to be moved is specified beforehand.
   It can be placed on top of a list which is either empty, or contains a letter that is larger (b can be placed on c, but not otherwise).
   The letter should be removed from the original list after it has been moved.
*/

move_letter(Letter, Lists, Result) :-
    % search Letter, Temp0 miss amended list [Letter|Rest]
    nth1(I, Lists, [Letter|Rest], Temp0),
    % reinsert Rest, Temp1 just miss Letter
    nth1(I, Temp1, Rest, Temp0),
    % search an appropriate place to insert Letter
    nth1(J, Temp1, Candidate, Temp2),
    % insertion constraints
    J \= I, (Candidate = [] ; Candidate = [C|_], C @> Letter),
    % update Result
    nth1(J, Result, [Letter|Candidate], Temp2).
```

Usage examples:

```
?- move_letter(a,[[b,c],[],[a]],R).
R = [[a, b, c], [], []] ;
R = [[b, c], [a], []] ;
false.

?- move_letter(b,[[b,c],[],[a]],R).
R = [[c], [b], [a]] ;
false.
```

I followed this 'not idiomatic' route to ease the check that the insertion occurs at different place than deletion.

Comment: The `nth0/3-4` and `nth1/3-4` are usually *library* predicates, not *built-in* predicates. For questions that don't specify a particular Prolog implementation, it's a good idea to always add a note on the use of non standard (official or de facto) predicates.

Comment: Thanks @PauloMoura. You're right, of course. There was some time ago also a question about implementing nth1/4, I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9803727/874024)

Answer (score 0):

Below are some rules to find lists that starts with some element.

```
starts_with([H|T], H). 
find_starts_with([],C,[]).
find_starts_with([H|T],C,[H|Y]) :- starts_with(H,C),find_starts_with(T,C,Y).
find_starts_with([H|T],C,L) :- \+ starts_with(H,C), find_starts_with(T,C,L).
```

Example:

```
| ?- find_starts_with([[1,2],[3,4],[1,5]],1,X).

X = [[1,2],[1,5]] ? ;
```

Comment: Thank you! This already a step into the good direction, but how would you recommend me to remove the top of that list and put it on top of another list which is either empty or contains a larger letter?

Comment: Can you provide an example in terms of input/output ?

Comment: Input could be (b, [[b,c],[],[a]], X), output should be X = [[c],[b],[a]]

Answer (score 0):

I like @CapelliC's concise solution. Here's an alternative solution that doesn't use the `nth1` built-in. Apologies for the sucky variable names.

```
% move_letter : Result is L with the letter C removed from the beginning
% of one sublist and re-inserted at the beginning of another sublist
% such that the new letter is less than the original beginning letter
% of that sublist
%
move_letter(C, L, Result) :-
    removed_letter(C, L, R, N),        % Find & remove letter from a sublist
    insert_letter(C, R, 0, N, Result). % Result is R with the letter inserted

% removed_letter : R is L with the letter C removed from the beginning of a
% sublist. The value N is the position within L that the sublist occurs 
%
removed_letter(C, L, R, N) :-
    removed_letter(C, L, R, 0, N).
removed_letter(C, [[C|T]|TT], [T|TT], A, A).
removed_letter(C, [L|TT], [L|TTR], A, N) :-
    A1 is A + 1,
    removed_letter(C, TT, TTR, A1, N).

% Insert letter in empty sublist if it's not where the letter came from;
% Insert letter at front of a sublist if it's not where the letter came from
% and the new letter is less than the current head letter;
% Or insert letter someplace later in the list of sublists
%
insert_letter(C, [[]|TT], A, N, [[C]|TT]) :-
    A \== N.
insert_letter(C, [[C1|T]|TT], A, N, [[C,C1|T]|TT]) :-
    A \== N,
    C @< C1.
insert_letter(C, [L|TT], A, N, [L|TTR]) :-
    A1 is A + 1,
    insert_letter(C, TT, A1, N, TTR).
```

Results in:

```
| ?- move_letter(a, [[b,c],[],[a]], R).

R = [[a,b,c],[],[]] ? a

R = [[b,c],[a],[]]

no

| ?- move_letter(b, [[b,c],[],[a]], R).

R = [[c],[b],[a]] ? a

no

| ?- move_letter(b, [[b,c], [], [a], [b,d]], R).

R = [[c],[b],[a],[b,d]] ? a

R = [[b,c],[b],[a],[d]]

no
```

Comment: Also a very great contribution! I think it is good to avoid built-in predicates when possible. Thank you.

Comment: @Boreq thanks. Technically, predicates like `is/2` are a built-in predicate, so this solution doesn't totally avoid built-in predicates. But it does stick with ISO constructs and would work in most Prolog interpreters. The nice thing about seeing different solutions is that there's something about Prolog programming to be learned in each case. :)